# Unirest no class found error

Tags: java, runtime-error, unirest

I'm trying to use the unirest library to make some requests, but when I try to use it I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/HttpRequest   at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)  at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)  at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
>     at incandescent.Interface.main(Interface.java:14) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpRequest     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     ... 29 more

I did imported the required libraries to my path in Eclipse as the following printscreen shows:

[image]

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1):

You need to add httpcore jar in your classpath, Unirest uses httpcore. Download jar from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar and add to classpath then compile.

It is always better to use dependency management tool like maven. When you use maven unirest dependency, it takes care of downloading httpcore jar too.

Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
      <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I do not understand why people down vote without any comment. Please leave comment if you are down voting. Be it question or answer.